# How to continue function when error is thrown in withCallingHandlers in R

Tags: r, error-handling

I'm writing a test case for an R function that tests whether an error is being thrown and caught correctly at a certain point in the function and I'm having some trouble getting the test to continue when an error is thrown during execution in withCallingHandlers(...). I'm using this approach:

```
counter <- 0
withCallingHandlers({
testingFunction(df0, df1)
testingFunction(df2, df3)
testingFunction(df4, df5)

}, warning=function(war){
    print(paste(war$message))
}, error=function(err){
    print(paste(err$message))
    if(err$message == paste("The function should throw this error message",
                              "at the right time.")){
        counter <<- counter + 1
    }

})

stopifnot(counter == 2)
```

The problem I'm running into is that the script is exiting after the first error is (successfully) caught and I'm not sure how to handle the error so that after it's caught, withCallingHandlers simply continues onto the next part of its execution. I understand that it has something to do with a restart object but I'm not sure how to use them correctly. Does anyone know how I could manipulate the above code so that execution of withCallingHandlers(...) continues even when an error is caught?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just wrap each call to `testingFunction` with a call to `tryCatch`.:

```
counter <- 0
testForExpectedError <- function(expr) {
    tryCatch(expr, error=function(err) {
        print(paste(err$message))
        if(err$message == paste("The function should throw this error message",
                                "at the right time.")){
            counter <<- counter + 1
        }
    })
}

testForExpectedError(testingFunction(df0, df1))
testForExpectedError(testingFunction(df2, df3))
testForExpectedError(testingFunction(df4, df5))

stopifnot(counter == 2)
```

Answer (score 6):

For a test function

```
fun1 = function() stop("something specific went wrong")
```

the idiom

```
obs = tryCatch(fun1(), error=conditionMessage)
exp = "something specific went wrong"
stopifnot(identical(exp, obs))
```

is maybe a tidier version of Ryan's, and like his avoids the unfortunate case where an error is thrown but for the wrong reason. The same paradigm works for warnings

```
fun2 = function(x) as.integer(x)
obs = tryCatch(fun2(c("1", "two")), warning=conditionMessage)
stopifnot(identical("NAs introduced by coercion", obs))
```

and to check for 'clean' evaluation

```
obs = tryCatch(fun2(c("1", "2")), warning=conditionMessage, 
          error=conditionMessage)
stopifnot(identical(1:2, obs))
```

This is ok, provided `Sys.getlocale()` is "C" or another encoding that doesn't change the translation of the condition messages.